# How to delete rows in a data frame with for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I want to delete some rows based on a condition.

I tried to drop as it is explained in the website.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
jobs
   job_name  number
0  job1      163
1  job2      200
2  job3      3
```

And I have a list:

`my_jobs = [job2, job3]`

My condition:

```
for job in jobs['job_name']:
    if job not in my_jobs:
        jobs_df.drop(job, axis=0)
```

And I want my dataframe looks like this:

```
jobs
   job_name  number
1  job2      200
2  job3      3
```

However, I'm getting:

> keyerror:"['jo1'] not found in axis"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `jobs_df = jobs_df[jobs_df['job_name'].isin(my_jobs)]`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cause of the error is that it is looking for the job_name in the dataframe index which only has [0, 1, 2]
you could set the column job_name as index:

```
jobs_df.set_index("job_name", inplace=True)
```

and then do:

```
my_jobs = ["job2", "job3"]
for job in jobs_df.index:
    if job not in my_jobs:
        jobs_df.drop(job, axis=0, inplace=True)
jobs_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

but an easier and faster way to do this would be to just do:

```
jobs_df = jobs_df[jobs_df["job_name"].isin(my_jobs)]
```

Comment: Hi, is ~ necessary? The code worked, however I think it did not give me the correct result.. I assume ~ means No?

Comment: @sarahkim You are right, the `~` means not. You do not need it. it is just a mistake.